# Contour Integral over a closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is the integral here not equal to zero? Using the above corollary:

$\gamma$ is closed ; $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ is continuous on any open set and $\displaystyle F(z)=\frac{2}{3}z^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is a primitive for $f(z)$?

Answer (score 4):

$f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ is not continuous. Try looking at $z$ just above and just below the negative real axis.